# Access initial parameter value while navigating with angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The entry point to my application is an URL with an unknown parameter value, e.g.:

```
http://www.host.com/key/25
```

and my simplified configuration looks like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: "/key/:key",
        component: 'home'
}).state('sitenotice', {
        url: "/sitenotice/",
        component: 'sitenotice'
});
```

I try to navigate to "sitenotice" and back to "main" in the index.html with:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  ...
  <div ui-view></div>

  <a ui-sref="sitenotice">site notice</a>
  <a ui-sref="home">home</a>
</html>
```

It is not working, because I don't pass the key-Parameter to the state "home". I have no idea how to access the initial value. Or can it be cached somehow? Is it possible to do that just with ui-router, I don't use a root-controller yet.

I use angular 1.5.8 and angular-ui-router 1.0.0-beta.3.

Comment: After you have get the parameter(:key) from stateParams, you can keep it in rootscope or pass it to the next state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is using the rootScope and store the parameter value there. I also made an update to angular-ui-router 1.0.0-rc.1. When leaving the "home"-state, $rootScope.navKey gets the current state parameter value.

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.run(function ($rootScope, $stateParams, $transitions) {
  $rootScope.navKey = "";

  $transitions.onExit({ exiting: 'home' }, function() {
    if (angular.isDefined($stateParams.key)) {
        $rootScope.navKey = $stateParams.key;
    }
  });
});
```

In my index.html I use the navKey to go back to the "main"-state:

```
<a ui-sref="home({ key: navKey })">
  <md-button md-no-ink="" class="md-primary">Home</md-button>
</a>
```